# Server Client Chat application in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am doing this simple chat application between one client and a server by establishing the socket connection between them.But it is going in infinite loop. Can anyone say what is the mistake i have done...

**CLIENT CODE**

```
    int main(){

    int client_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int connection_status = connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    char server_response[256];
    while(1){
    read(client_socket, server_response, sizeof(server_response));
    printf("Server:%s\n",server_response);
    printf("Client:");
    write(client_socket, server_response, sizeof(server_response));
    if(strncmp("exit",server_response,4)==0){
                    printf("Server Exit Successful");
                    break;
            }
    }
    close(client_socket);
    return 0;
  }
```

**SERVER CODE**

```
    int main(){

    char server_message[256];

    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port=htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

    bind(server_socket,(struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    listen(server_socket,1);

    int network_socket = accept(server_socket,NULL,NULL);
    while(1){
            write(network_socket,server_message,sizeof(server_message));
            printf("Client:%s\n",server_message);
            printf("Server:");
            read(network_socket,server_message,sizeof(server_message));
            if((strncmp(server_message,"exit",4))==0)
            {
                    printf("Client Exit...\n");
                    break;
            }
    }
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;
     }
```

Comment: "*what is the mistake*" one is, that you miss to show the relevant code. Thus the question is likely to receive downvotes and closure soon ...

Comment: Given the available information, no.

Comment: post some code, please

Comment: i have added code...

Comment: "*it is going in infinite loop*" why would you expect it to behave differently?

Comment: You ignore return values of functions you call, which is as good as not calling them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that you don't give your client an address to connect to. INADDR_ANY isn't going to magically locat the correct server ip address. 
That will not result in an infinite loop of course, but it will result in your server listening forever for a connection it will never get, which may look like an infinite loop.
Your client will go into an infinite loop because your loop is infinite and you don't check for an error after your connect syscall.